# How to create a task that runs in the background in Android

Tags: java, android

I recently got into Android development and I'm currently working on an App that will alert the user if his/her game server goes down whether he/she has the app opened or not. To do this, I would need to have the app running the background with a task that would ping the server every x seconds/minutes/etc. How can I create a task that runs in the background until the user shuts off their phone?

Comment: what you need is a running `Service`. There are literally tons of examples, you can start with the official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

For this i will suggest you links:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-service-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a timer. [CountDownTimers in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

In the "onFinish()" event. I would call a new timer and also execute what ever code you need to have, such as a push notification or update the server with new data.